# How to set a CSS background-image with URL in Dart?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to find a equivalent to [jQuery.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method

In my specific case, I want to set a background image for a canvas.

in jQuery, it would be:

```javascript
 $("#canvas").css("background-image", "url(./assets/gridPattern.png)");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to acess CSS properties via the [style attribute in Element](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Element.html#style)

```dart
query("#canvas").style.backgroundImage = "url(./assets/gridPattern.png)";
```